# How do I permanently remove my wireless interface?

Tags: wireless

How do I remove the device driver for my.

```
        description: Wireless interface
        product: AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168C:1C]
        vendor: Atheros Communications Inc. [168C]
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
        logical name: wlan0
        version: 01
        serial: 00:24:d2:13:78:86
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=3.2.0-38-generic-pae firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
```

Answer (score 3):

The driver is the kernel module `ath5k`.

You can prevent it from being loaded by adding `blacklist ath5k` to a new file in `/etc/modprobe.d`. In a terminal, run:

```
echo blacklist ath5k | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-custom.conf
```

The driver is part of the standard Ubuntu kernel and so cannot be completed removed unless you compile your own kernel excluding it.